# file_exists with relative path not working

Tags: php

`file_exists` not working.. Have also tried with `realpath`.. Same issue

First checking if the file exists.. `file_exists` returns false but the file is loaded anyway

```
chdir(__DIR__.'/../..');

$file = 'frontend.php';

echo "$file\n";
if(file_exists($file)){
    echo "File found\n";
}
else{
    echo "File not found\n";
}

require $file;
```

## output

```
frontend.php
File not found
Contents of frontend.php
```

Comment: What's your folder/file structure?

Comment: And what's the current include_path? Where is frontend.php relative to this script?

Comment: are you sure if the file is loaded successfully ? have you tried absolute path ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [php.net/file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists) says, the file_exists() function requires:

> Path to the file or directory.

So try pre-pending with the path of the directory:

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . $file)) {
    echo "File found\n";
}
```

Comment: you could also use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` from php 5.3+

Comment: That is correct, but let's be backward compatible as we don't know for sure what PHP version we're using in this example.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `file_exists()` caches its result. You can try `clearstatcache()` to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like that:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/frontend.php';
if(file_exists($file)){
    //...
}
```

Comment: you could also use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` from php 5.3+